# Unicode conversion to String leaves leading Byte order mark

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, c#-3.0, byte-order-mark

In my .NET 3.5 C# application I'm converting a unicode encoded byte array to a string.

The byte array is as follows:

```
{255, 254, 85, 0, 83, 0, 69, 0}
```

Using `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(var)`, I convert the byte array to a string, which returns:

```
{65279 '', 85 'U', 83 'S' , 69 'E'}
```

The leading character, `65279`, seems to be a [Zero Width No-Break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm), which is used as a Byte Order Mark in Unicode encoding, and its appearance is causing problems in the rest of my application.

Currently the workaround I'm using is `var.Trim(new char[]{'\uFEFF','\u200B'});`, which works just fine.

But the question really is, shouldn't `GetString`take care of removing the byte order mark? Or am I doing something wrong when converting the byte array?

Comment: @bzlm: _"Encoding.Unicode will likely return an UTF-16 encoder"_ -- no "likely" about it. It had _better_ do so, given that's what it's documented to do: ["An encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why are you trimming `\u200B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `GetString()` should not be removing the BOM. The BOM is actually a perfectly valid Unicode character (selected specifically because if it appears in the middle of a Unicode file, e.g. if the file was the result of concatenating multiple Unicode files, it won't affect the rendered text) and must be decoded along with all other characters in the `byte[]`.

The only code that ought to be interpreting and filtering out the BOM would be code that understands the data is coming from some persistent storage, e.g. `StreamReader`. And note that it will do that only if you don't disable that behavior.

All that `GetString()` should do is interpret the actual encoded characters and convert them to the text they represent (of course, in C# strings are stored internally as UTF16, so there's very little to that conversion when the original data is already in UTF16 :) ).

Comment: But where does the BOM come from? Looking at the byte array I do not see its binary representation.

Comment: @CristianoSousa 255 254 is the "BOM", i.e. the space. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @CristianoSousa: as commenter bzlm says, it's in your original data. `255` == `0xff` and `254` == `0xfe`. So the first two bytes in this little-endian UTF16 encoding resolve to `0xfeff`, or `65279` decimal. Just as you see in the decoded text.